# Getting null when I @Autowired for the interface in Junit Test

Tags: java, spring, junit

I'm writing JUnit test for this method `processData` - I'm doing `@Autowired` `Cache mycache` in Junit, and mocking `Cache mycache` under my Test method. When I'm doing this `mycache = mock(Cache.class)` - this returns some object in Junit method but when I invoke my actual method  from Junit `Cache mycache` going as null in `Main` class. Please find the code below:

What I'm missing here - how to resolve this NullPointer exception issue - why mycache is going as null when actual method triggered from Junit - though I've mocked this object. Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you!

**Main.Java**

```
import com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.Cache;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Main {

    @Autowired
    Cache mycache;

    public Product processData(String productId) {

    System.out.println("productId value: " +productId);
    System.out.println("mycache value: " +mycache);

        Product product = (Product) mycache.getIfPresent(productId); //getting NullPointer exception here
        if (product != null) {
            return product;
        }
        // do some processing
        return product;
    }
}
```

**MainTest.Java**

```
public class MainTest {
    @Autowired
    Cache mycache;

    @Test
    public void processDataTest() throws Exception {
        Main main = new Main();
        mycache = mock(Cache.class);
        System.out.println("mycache: " + mycache.toString()); // Mock for Cache, hashCode: 3244883
        when(mycache.getIfPresent("9393939")).thenReturn(null);
        Product product = main.processData("9393939");
        assertNotNull(product);
    }
}
```

**Exception Log trace:**

```
mycache: Mock for Cache, hashCode: 3244883
        productId value: 9393939
        mycache value: null

        java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.test.processData(Main.java:122)
        at com.test.MainTest.processDataTest(MainTest.java:161)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
```

Comment: `@Autowired Cache mycache;` this has no effect in your class. who is supposed to resolve that `@Autowired`? and then later you do `mycache = mock(Cache.class);`? this makes no sense at all

Comment: I'm using this Cache from Caffeine library (com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.Cache)  in my Main class, how can I use this Cache object under my junit test class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing:

```
@Component
public class Main {

   @Autowired
   Cache mycache;
   ...
```

Inject it via a constructor:

```
  @Component
  public class Main {
      private final Cache mycache;

      public Main(Cache mycache) {
          this.mycache = mycache;
      }
  }
```

Now it your test you can create an instance of `Main` where you can provide a *mock* of `Cache`.

Comment: Throws "*org.junit.runners.model.InvalidTestClassError: Invalid test class 'com.company.core.service.impl.unit.DemoTest':
  1. Test class should have exactly one public zero-argument constructor*" error

Comment: @Robert this answer has helped OP, though the error _does_ mean something else, yes. What is your _actual_ problem with it? You have a question/situation where this happens?

Comment: Thanks for reply. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69313791/java-spring-cannot-test-caching-in-unit-test?noredirect=1#comment122513106_69313791) is my problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `@Autowired` a class in your test case you are not supposed to mock it. You will need to annotate the Cache field with `@Mock` or else you would not able to mock the Cache.class.

The reason you are getting null at processData is because the Cache object is autowired and not mocked.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.test.processData(Main.java:122)
```

Could you please try the below code instead,

```
public class MainTest {

    @Mock
    Cache mycache;

    @Test
    public void processDataTest() throws Exception {
        Main main = new Main();
        // mycache = mock(Cache.class);
        System.out.println("mycache: " + mycache.toString()); // Mock for Cache, hashCode: 3244883
        when(mycache.getIfPresent("9393939")).thenReturn(null);
        Product product = main.processData("9393939");
        assertNotNull(product);
    }
}
```

Comment: how is this `@Autowired Main main;` supposed to be resolved? this answer makes zero sense

Comment: Yes this resolved the issue, and I tried your option as well even that worked. Appreciated your help @Eugene

Comment: @LearningJava how can it "resolve the issue"? there is no spring context that can provide that `@Autowired` - `main` is going to be null, always.

Comment: @Eugene, I've only added the Autowired on Main class because as it is annotated with Component it is a good practice to inject rather than initialising an object inside the testcase. The answer provided by me is in assumption that the spring context would be present as the main class is annotated as Component. I was also confused by the class name but seems like this is added by the author just as an example.

Comment: it is irrelevant what annotation is on `Main` class, as `MainTest` has zero spring annotations.

Comment: @Eugene I get your point either the test should have spring annotations or the Main class should have an object earlier.